# Создание триггера Firebird

Tags: sql, база-данных, firebird, триггер

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос, как правильно создать триггер Firebird. Раньше я не работал с триггерами и пока не понял, как правильно их реализовать.
Что должен делать триггер: При вставке и обновлении столбцов "Сумма" и "Оплачено", если они не пустые, автоматически вычислять столбец "Долг", т.е. сумма минус оплата.
Что я делал:

```
CREATE trigger cash_after_ui for "КАССА"
active after insert or update position 0
as
begin
if (OLD."Сумма" is not null and
  OLD."Оплачено" is not null) then
begin
   NEW."Долг" = OLD."Сумма" - OLD."Оплачено";
end
end
```

Но я так понял, что здесь что-то неправильно, т.к. результат "This column cannot be updated because it is derived from an SQL function or expression.
attempted update of read-only column.", хотя столбец далеко не только для чтения.

И посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хорошую книгу по SQL с примерами, особенно триггеры и процедуры, т.к. мануал по Firebird не очень подробно описывает данные вещи.
Спасибо.

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:

```
CREATE trigger cash_before_ui for "КАССА"
    active before insert or update position 0
    as
    begin
       NEW."Долг" = OLD."Сумма" - OLD."Оплачено";
    end
```

Теперь все работает :)

Comment: Оказывается, в AFTER триггерах нельзя менять поля NEW и OLD :(

Comment: Получилось все сделать, когда сделал триггер BEFORE.  Но книгу посоветуйте ))

Comment: Может просто сделать поле Долг вычисляемым? Тогда триггер вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

По Firebird есть одна хорошая книга: Хелен Борри "Firebird. Руководство разработчика баз данных".

А если с SQL в принципе вы знакомы, и нужно лишь узнать/вспомнить особенности Firebird, то лучше всего взять Firebird Language Reference (Russian) с официального сайта https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/.